# Radiosity lightmap generation

Tags: c++, algorithm, lighting

Is there any working C++ source code for a lightmap generation algorithm using Radiosity or any other GI system? I've found technical papers only, but I can't really find any implementation.

Comment: http://zhlt.info/download-zhlt.html - you might find the source code of "hlrad" (Half-Life RADiosity lightmap compiler) useful. It's not "true C++" but it shouldn't be hard to make sense of it.